# Is there any way to debug Geoserver WPS deployment?

Tags: geoserver, error, wps, log

There are many reasons for Geoserver WPS processes to fail when initializing, but the most possible is missing dependences. Anyway, it is not always clear which one, since Geoserver provides absolutely no output when a process fails to init for some reason. Setting `log4j.category.org.geoserver=TRACE` and `log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout` in `resources\log4j.properties` does nothing in my Geoserver 2.11.0 standalone.

Only thing I need is a message that shows what is wrong with a process class. Any directions please?

Comment: You might get more out of the geotools side - suggest adding some logging there too.

Comment: @BradHards Thanks, but it does not help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning logging up to `GEOTOOLS-DEVELOPER` in the global settings has always worked for me for missing dependencies, there is an error thrown on startup when the WPS processes are loaded, saying why a process is being dropped.

The other way is to [run GeoServer in eclipse](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/eclipse-guide/#id3) (or other IDE) and debugging there.